# How to reduce the number of spell-check languages/dialects

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Even when I install Libre-Office (3.6.1) in advanced mode and only select Dutch, German, English and French as spell-check languages, I still find many more dialects (German-German + Austrian-German + Swiss German and the same for French, English and Dutch).

How can I make sure that I ONLY have US-English, DE-German, FR-French and NL-Dutch spell-checking?

Comment: @Pedro, I think you are right, I am so used to working here that I forgot about Super User. Any idea how I can migrate instead of delete/create.

Comment: Try these links for information on how to migrate (basically you have to close you own question asking a moderator to migrate it): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/how-to-migrate-a-question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91381/how-to-migrate-question-to-programmers-stackexchange-com and http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-migrate-questions-from-stackoverflow.